# How can I hide/unhide app icon programmatically in Java ? Is it possible in latest androids?

Tags: java, android, react-native, module, native

I want to hide app onclick in a react-native application, I am using custom native modules. But the problem is that the app Closes but never hides the icon.
I am using Virtual Device, Pixel 7 Pro, Android 14.
Also tell me if it requires any custom permissions.

I tried to do it through an existing method:

```
package com.icicapp;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;

public class HideAppModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public HideAppModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HideAppModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void hideAppIcon() {
        PackageManager pm = reactContext.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                reactContext.getComponentName(),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Log.d("HideAppModule", "App icon hidden successfully!"); // Add this line
    }

}
```